# Accessing Object Instance from Pointer during Runtime in C++

Tags: c++

I am implementing the xbeep library. I found that this snippet will work in a main loop:

```cpp
libxbee::XBee xbee("xbee3", "/dev/ttyUSB0", 9600);
myCB con(xbee, "Data", &address);
con << "Hello World";
```

However since I will be creating the connection during runtime, I modified the above code so that the object is created when a method for creating the connection is called. Instead of being objects, I declared them as pointers:

```cpp
libxbee::XBee* xbee;
connectionCB* con;
```

Then when opening the connection, I instantiated them:

```cpp
void XbeeController::XbeeController::openXbeeConnection(QString port, int bRate, QString deviceAddr)
{
    baudRate = bRate;
xbee = new libxbee::XBee(DEVICE_REV, "/dev/ttyUSB0", 9600); //Burnt values for proof of concept.
con = new connectionCB(*xbee, "Data", &address);
}
```

My code now fails

```cpp
void XbeeController::XbeeController::sendXbeeMessage(std::string message)
{
con << message;
}
```

> **Error**: invalid operands of types ‘xbee::connectionCB*’ and ‘char*’ to binary ‘operator<<’
>       con << "Hello World";
>       ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

How can I treat `con` as an object instead of a pointer so that it works like before?

Comment: You don't need to use `new` to create variables at runtime.  You're original code block should work.  If it doesn't, please post the code you are trying to get to work.

Comment: "since I will be creating the connection during runtime" in your first snippet the connection **is** created during runtime

Comment: When asking questions about build errors, first of all please try to create a [mcve] that replicates the error and show it to us. Then copy-paste the full and complete output of building that example. And lastly please make sure that the example and the error message match, right now your error message you show doesn't match any of the code you show.

Comment: Also don't use tags that aren't relevant to the question or the problem. While you use `QString` in a couple of places, the Qt framework is really irrelevant to the problem you have, so its tag should not really be listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now `con` is a pointer, but `operator<<()` asks for reference and probably defined something like:
`connectionCB &operator<<(connectionCB &cb, const char *str);`

Use:
`*con << "Hello World";`